# Show error when i wrote import java.io.*;

Tags: java, ubuntu

why i am getting error when i write import java.io.*; in java file ?

```
dev_ps@DPS:~/Desktop/MorningDose$ javac dev.java
----------
1. WARNING in /home/dev_ps/Desktop/MorningDose/dev.java (at line 2)
    import java.io.*;
           ^^^^^^^

The import java.io is never used
```

Comment: Because, "The import java.io is never used"? (and it's a warning, not an error).

Comment: its not error its a warning, you import it but never used it in your class.. just leave it because compiled byte code class file will ignore it so there is not any performance issue or like that

Comment: @DevendraPratapSingh compiling the class doesn't execute it. I've tried to explain it a bit in my answer

Answer (score 1):

With `javac` you're compiling your program, you're not running it!

after using the command `javac dev.java` a class file `dev.class` is created. If you have defined a main method in the java file you can execute the java-program with the command:

`java dev`

In order to understand the difference between compilation and execution you should defenetly read something about these two topics!

---

To your original question:

`The import java.io is never used` is a warning which tells you that you use no functionality from `java.io`. That means you can delete the line `import java.io.*;` (or any alike that isn't used) from your code!

Comment: thanx @parkerhalo.. i got it

Answer (score 1):

It is warning you that you are not using the import, so it is useless. It will still run with this, but generally it is considered correct to only import what you use.

Answer (score 0):

Its only a warning, Java compiler warning you because, your not using any class from java.io package. The good practice is remove all un used imports from your classes. Otherwise it will load all the classes while class load time when application start to execute.

Also if you want to load any class from other package declare only to specific class for eg: if your using BUfferedReader, use as follow

import java.io.BufferedReader;